# Which Android version first featured auto-upgrade?

Tags: applications, android-versions, application-autoupdate

Modern Android versions enable auto-upgrading installed apps.

Which Android (or play store / market app) version first featured this?

Comment: You're on the wrong path, Adam. It's not *Android* enabling that, but the corresponding "market apps" (e.g. Google Play Store). So it has nothing to do with the Android version. Apart from that, what's the practical background of this question? What issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the info. I am investigation some strange behavior pattern in an app, which might be related to version upgrades, and it would be helpful to know whether the user upgraded the app manually or not.

Comment: hard to tell that remotely. Playstore offers automatic updates, but one can turn those off. One can sideload apps from different sources in different ways as well. There's an `installer` flag when dumping package details which *can* help identifying the source (but that shows "unknown" when not installed via an app, i.e. when using `adb install` or `pm install` manually, or having downloaded the `.apk` to the device and installed from e.g. a file manager). But what you most likely mean is whether between v1 and v3 the v2 was skipped. Not sure if that's on-topic here (being a dev question).